# Showing wrong information for Sentinel 5p L2 CO data in VISAN using HARP

Tags: sentinel-5p

I am using VISAN (Anaconda) IDL for opening Sentinel 5P L2 CO dataset in netcdf format. Whenever I have tried to open the file using the code

`S5P_L2_CO = harp.import_product(r"F:\sentinel 5p\New folder\S5P_OFFL_L2__CO_____20200101T055716_20200101T073846_11490_01_010302_20200102T194736.nc")`

It works Ok. But when I use

`wplot`

then it shows "Surface Meridional Wind Velocity". No CO is found. I have tried with three dataset. The visualization is same.

[image]

[image]

My quesiton is am i doing any wrong or the dataset wrongly submitted in the sentinel5p server.

Here it need to mention, I have used SO2 data, it works like as it should be.